# select max value in each 5 rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, greatest-n-per-group

My total rows are variable and not fixed , So there are N rows and I want to separate each 5 rows as a group and select the max value of price in following table in SQL.

```
Date     Price
20170101 100
20170102 110
20170103 90
20170105 80
20170109 76

20170110 50
20170111 55
20170113 80
20170115 100
20170120 99

20170121 88
20170122 98
20170123 120
```

So in first 5 group the max price is 110 , and second group is 100, and last group max price is 120.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a common table expression to group them.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Rank, Price
             FROM yourtable)
SELECT (Rank - 1) / 5 AS GroupedDate, MAX(Price) AS MAXPRICE
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ((Rank - 1) / 5);
```

Output

```
GroupedDate MAXPRICE
0           110
1           100
2           120
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5857/3/0

Comment: Worked Like a charm , let me know is it possible to have date of selected price also ?

Comment: As in something like : `20170101 - 20170109 110`

Comment: No like --> 20170102=110

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT grp, MAX(Price) AS price
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATE)  / 5 AS grp FROM tab) sub
GROUP BY grp;

-- OUTPUT
grp  price
0    110
1    100
2    120
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ULQA44921)**

*assuming that date is unique

**EDIT:**

> As in something like : 20170101 - 20170109 110

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MIN(DATE),112) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),MAX(date),112)
     , MAX(Price) AS price
FROM (SELECT *, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATE) ) / 5 AS grp FROM tab) sub
GROUP BY grp;
```

Output:

```
20170101-20170105   110
20170109-20170115   100
20170120-20170123   120
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/EIZRFX30742)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number as below

```
;With cte as (
Select *, Bucket = Sum(RowN) over(Order by [date]) from (
    Select *, RowN = case when row_number()  over(order by [date]) % 5 = 0 then 1 else 0 end from #data1
) a
) Select top (1) with ties [Date], [Price]
from cte 
order by row_number() over (partition by Bucket order by Price desc)
```